# Python: lazy submodule imports invalidate parent modules > UnboundLocalError - But why?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

Considering the following code:
I'm using a submodule allover my code and a special submodule (might be uber heavy to load) in only one function so I'm lazy importing:

```
import xml.etree

def y():
    print(xml.etree.__name__)

def x():
    print(xml.etree.__name__)

    import xml.dom
    print(xml.dom.__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    y()
    x()
```

This will result in `xml` being unbound:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'xml' referenced before assignment
```

(yes to fix it I can move the import up within the function OR do `from xml import dom`)

I'd love to know what happens here.
Apparently the imports are evaluated just before Python is entering the function.

What's the **reasoning** behind this?

Comment: good question. you can also fix it by using `global xml`, but i'm not totally sure what that means...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imports are not evaluated before entering the function, but the function body is parsed for assignments before execution. Any name bound in an assignment is considered a name local to the function, since the beginning of the body. As an `import` is an implicit form of assignment, the name `xml` just becomes local to the function. But you are using it before the `import` assignment. So the error is actually quite obvious.

To fix it you can do as you say or simply use `global`:

```
import xml.etree

def y():
    print(xml.etree.__name__)

def x():
    global xml
    print(xml.etree.__name__)

    import xml.dom
    print(xml.dom.__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    y()
    x()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the same in a simpler example:

```py
a = 1

def foo():
    print(a)  # works

def bar():
    print(a)  # gives error
    a = 2
    print(a)
    
foo()
bar()
```

This gives:

```
1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

The reason is that local variables (like global variables) are determined *at compile time*, overwriting global variables of the same name, but bound to the value only *at run-time*, so if they are accessed before the assignment, they are already known, but not yet defined (e.g. bound).

Answer (score -1):

Advice: Never traverse submodules using attributes (dot notation). This is very flaky and fragile. Sometimes those attributes exist. Next time they don't. Just never use them. Always import the inner-most module (or member)

Instead of this:

```py
import xml.dom
print(xml.dom.__name__)
```

Use this:

```py
from xml import dom
print(dom.__name__)
```

As for why your issue happens, remember the weird semantics of `import foo.bar.baz` which actually sets `foo`  variable, not `baz`. And then all Python's "referenced before assignment" start to apply.